# 1980s Vampires/creatures movie about a group of people against the creatures that bleed black

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to figure out a vampires/creatures movie I had watched long back. I do not remember if the creatures shown in the movie were vampires or not. I only remember details from a specific scene of the movie, which I will mention below.

The creatures in the movie bleed black. There is a group of people that are fighting the creatures, trying to stay alive. This group is being lead by a young guy or at least he seems like the head of the pack. There are some girls in that group as well. Then there is another guy who is like a lone wolf i.e. by himself and not a part of the group. The leader of the group and the single guy clearly don't like each other and the leader does not want the other guy to come with them.

But in the scene, all the people are in a building and are being attacked by the creatures. The lone guy asks the group to leave and takes on the creatures alone as far as the group is concerned. The group moves on ahead and the lone guy after a fight which has not been shown, catches up with the group. He is drenched in the creatures black blood  from head to toe after the fight and has been established in the scene as a badass and the group agrees to include him.

I also remember razor discs being used as weapons either by the creatures or humans. Additionally the lone guy or the single guy in the movie is dressed in black, wears a black leather jacket, has greasy hair parted sideways and looks somewhat like Willem Dafoe.

The movie most likely is from 1980s.

I have checked all Willem Dafoe movies but I did not find the one I am looking for. Razor discs have been used in Ghosts of Mars as well, but that is not the movie either.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a really good description and well written! If you remember anything else please [edit] that into your question. You may also want to take the [tour] to learn a bit about how the site works!

Comment: Hmm... no apparent hits on https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlackBlood

Comment: Two different movies come to mind with this description. Could it be 1. Tales From the Crypt: Demon Night (vampires/demons, black blood, main character is William Sadler who maybe could be your Willem Dafoe-ish character, definitely wears a black leather jacket and is tough, but I don't remember razor discs) or 2. I Come In Peace/Dark Angel (has razor discs, Dolph Lundgren, black leather jacket, and future space vampire drug dealer, but I don't remember black blood) Do either of those seem familiar?